# method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, abstract

I am creating a mock employee database using inheritance and polymorphism. I am running into the following errors when trying to override the superclass methods.

```
HourlyEmployee is not abstract and does not override abstract method resetWeek() in Employee
public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee
   ^
HourlyEmployee.java:43: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
HourlyEmployee.java:54: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
HourlyEmployee.java:60: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
HourlyEmployee.java:66: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
```

Here is my Employee Superclass and HourlyEmployee Subclass code

```
public abstract class Employee
{
protected String firstName;
protected String lastName;
protected char middleInitial;
protected boolean fulltime;
private char gender;
private int employeeNum;

public Employee (String fn, String ln, char m, char g, int empNum, boolean ft)
{
    firstName = fn;
    lastName = ln;
    middleInitial = m;
    gender = g;
    employeeNum = empNum;
    fulltime = ft;
}

public int getEmployeeNumber()
{
    return employeeNum;
}

public void setEmployeeNumber(int empNum)
{
    while (empNum <= 10000 && empNum >= 99999)
    {
        System.out.print ("Invalid input, please try again: ");
    }

    if (empNum >= 10000 && empNum <= 99999)
    {
        employeeNum = empNum;
    }
}

public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

public char checkGender(char g)
{
    if (g != 'M' || g != 'F')
    {
        g = 'F';
    }
    return g;
}

public char getGender()
{
    return gender;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object e2)
{
    if (this.employeeNum == ((Employee)e2).employeeNum)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return employeeNum + "\n" + lastName + ", " + firstName + "\n" + "Gender:" + gender + "\n" + "Status:" + fulltime + "\n";
}

public abstract double caclulateWeeklyPay();

public abstract void annualRaise();

public abstract double holidayBonus();

public abstract void resetWeek();
}
```

Here is the HourlyEmployee subclass

```
public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee
{
private double wage;
private double hoursWorked;
private double additionalHours;

public HourlyEmployee(String fn, String ln, char m, char g, int empNum, boolean ft, double w, double h, double ahours)
{
    super (fn, ln, m, g, empNum, ft);
    wage = w;
    hoursWorked = h;
    hoursWorked = 0.0;
    additionalHours = ahours;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return this.getEmployeeNumber() + "\n" + lastName + ", " + firstName + middleInitial + "\n" + "Gender: "
     + this.getGender() + "\n" + "Status: " + fulltime + "\n" + "Wage: " + wage + "\n" + "Hours Worked: " + hoursWorked + "\n";
}

   //@Override    
public double calculateWeeklyPay(double w, double h)
{
    if (h > 40)
    {
        w = w * 2;
    }

    return w * h;        
}

//@Override
public double annualRaise(double w)
{
    return (w * .05) + w;
}

//@Override
public double holidayBonus(double w)
{
    return w * 40;
}

//@Override
public double resetWeek(double h)
{
    h = 0.0;
    return h;
}

public double plusHoursWorked(double h, double ahours)
{
    while (h <= 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid value entered, please try again");
    }

    h += ahours;

    return h;
}


}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your Employee class has 4 abstract methods, none of which are implemented (not properly at least).  Here is an example:

```
double caclulateWeeklyPay(); // in Employee
double calculateWeeklyPay(double w, double h) // in HourlyEmployee
```

The parent class should contain the same signature (which includes parameters), and should look like this:

```
public abstract double calculateWeeklyPay(double w, double h);
```

Since this appears to be homework, I will leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 3):

Just read the error message carefully:

> HourlyEmployee is not abstract and does not override abstract method resetWeek() in Employee

It clearly indicates that your `Employee` class is `abstract` and has an abstract method `resetWeek()`.

Your class `HourlyEmployee` which extends from `Employee` is not abstract, so it should override all abstract methods of the super class, as a concrete class can not have any abstract methods.

The reason is that your methods in the `HourlyEmployee` class have a different signature than those in the super class. So the method is not overridden, and the `@Override` annotation is not accepted by the compiler

Answer (score 1):

as your **HourlyEmployee** **class is not abstract** you need to **implement the abstract methods declared in your EMPLOYEE abstract class**. which is quite obvious.
you have to implement the below methods

```
 public abstract double caclulateWeeklyPay();

 public abstract void annualRaise();

 public abstract double holidayBonus();

 public abstract void resetWeek();
```